# Recommendations for implementing the architecture in Keras

Tags: keras, deep-learning

What is a simple way to implement the following architecture using Keras.

[image: C2AE architecture]

There are two input encoders merged and the partial output is given to the decoder. The loss of the final layer propagated to the merged layer and the difference between the two encoders is back propagated to one encoder; the difference between the two network is added to the back-propagated output loss and passed to the other network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have started implementing it as follows:

```
Y=Input(shape=(100,),name='Fe_input')
y=Dense(100, activation=LeakyReLU(alpha=0.0001))(Y)
y=BatchNormalization()(y)
y=Dense(60, activation=LeakyReLU(alpha=0.0001))(y)
y=BatchNormalization()(y)
y=Dense(20, activation=LeakyReLU(alpha=0.0001))(y)
y=BatchNormalization()(y)

X=Input(shape=(512,),name='Fx_input')
x=Dense(100, activation=LeakyReLU(alpha=0.0001))(X)
x=BatchNormalization()(x)
x=Dense(60, activation=LeakyReLU(alpha=0.0001))(x)
x=BatchNormalization()(x)
x=Dense(20, activation=LeakyReLU(alpha=0.0001))(x)
x=BatchNormalization()(x)

merge_layer=concatenate([x,y], name='merge_layer')
# I need to push partial output to merge layer to the next layer. Not sure how to       
#do that.
x=Dense(60, activation=LeakyReLU(alpha=0.0001))(x)
x=BatchNormalization()(x)

Fd=Dense(100, activation='sigmoid')(x)
model=Model([X,Y],[merge_layer, Fd])
model.compile(...)
```

How can I take partial output and send it across the decoder part? Moreover how can the gradient during backprop be summed and pushed to one of the branches?